# Передача дополнительных параметров в callback функцию с использованием замыканий

Tags: функции, javascript, замыкания

Как видно из кода: при наступлении ***.onload*** имеет на входе ***e***, как передать в callback функцию значение ***i***, чтобы не заменить при этом необходимый ***e***?

```
for (var i in many_i) {

    image[i].onload = (function (e) {
        var important_val1 = e.target;
        var important_val2 = index;
    })(i);

}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Так не пробовали?

    for (var i in many_i) {
        var index = i;
        image.onload = (function (e) {
            var important_val1 = e.target;
            var important_val2 = index;
        });
    }

Кстати, вы в цикле устанавливаете onload для _одной и той же_ картинки, затирая каждой итерацией предыдущую — вам именно это нужно?

Comment: Спасибо. Так работает!
За неделю, уже второй раз сталкиваюсь с подобным и было бы полезно знать, можно ли передать дополнительные переменные в анонимную функцию не "затерев" переменные функции вызова.

*весь код просто выдуман.

Comment: @michael, да можно, просто оберните еще одним замыканием, которое вернет (return) функцию являющуюся хэндлером события.

Comment: @Vlad , странно что у вас это работает, область видимости ограничивается же не {} а function(){}... вот [наглядный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tUH46/) а вот [как должно быть](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tUH46/1/)

Comment: @eicto: И правда, спасибо за пример! В C# такое бы сработало, там область видимости ограничена именно скобками. Я не знаток JS.

Comment: ну javascript!=java и уж тем более javascript!=C# :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Замыкания - очень мощный инструмент, но пользоваться им надо с некоторой настороженностью =)

Дело в том, что в вашем примере, все созданные функции имеют доступ к переменной i из scope функции родителя. К *одной и той же* переменной i и при обращении к ней получают ее значение на момент обращения.

Для того чтобы перебороть такое поведение все что вам нужно - зафиксировать значение i на момент создания функции callback'a. Этого можно добиться добавив в код временную функцию, которая сохранит в своем scope текущее значение i и возвратит функцию обработчик, которая, в свою очередь, будет иметь доступ к значению i зафиксированному в scope родительской временной функции

Как то так.

```
var i;
for(i in many_i) {
    image[i].onload = (function(){
        var closedI = i;
        return function (e) {
            console.log(closedI, e);
        }
    })()
}
```

Более доступно тема раскрыта [здесь](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure)

Comment: не так разве ?

    for(i in many_i) {
        image[i].onload = (function(i){
            return function (e) {
                console.log(i, e);
            }
        })(i)
    }

ну и у вас в console.log не closedI а i

Comment: Да, ваш вариант выглядит почище. Эффект тот же, просто подход чуточку другой.

Спасибо, ошибку исправил

Comment: вообще тут более другой вопрос есть:

jslint ругается на создание функции в цикле, обойти можно но просто хаком, создать функцию отдельно, как то так:

    for(i in many_i) {
         image[i].onload = sethandler(i);
    }

    function sethandler(i){
        return function (e) {
            console.log(i, e);
        };
    }


как предполагается это делать иначе, я не знаю. в jquery это решается добавлением  .data() к объекту.

Comment: Ну, подумав, вынос генератора в именованную функцию не кажется таким уж плохим маневром. Более того, если хендлер не ограничивается парой строк, читабельность кода в jslint варианте даже получше будет ИМО.

А можно поподробнее про вариант с .data()? Не в полне понял.

Comment: ну вынос генератора в отдельную функцию не решает вопроса о генерации функции в цикле (суть того на что jslint ругается), насчет data  - всё просто, вместо того чтобы генерить разные  функции можно писать

    $.data(image[i],'index',i)

и потом в хэндлере
  
    var i=$.data(this,'index');

причем это работает как для объектов jquery, так и для любых других (исключая строки и цифры, для массивов уже работает, с исключением, что добавляется jQuery при for (var key in arr){})

Comment: вот валидный код с использованием jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tUH46/2/ (функция handlera одна и индекс передается)

Answer (score 0):

Любая функция в Javascript имеет ссылки на все переменные в том контексте где она объявлена, т.е если у вас функция объявлена внутри функции, внутренняя функция будет видеть все переменные внешней функции.
Для управление областью видимости следует использовать анонимные функции, с последующим вызовом.

Пример: Создание функций в цикле.

Если мы будем создавать функции которые будут просто печатать переменную `i` они все напечатают значение которое будет после завершение всего цикла, для того что бы передать конкретное значение на каждом шаге цикла нужно использовать inline вызов анонимной функции.

```
!function outer() {
    var functions = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i<3;i++) {
        //создаем и вызываем анонимную функцию,
        //которая будет пробрасывать нужный параметр
        //для создания внутренней функции
        !function(i) {
            functions.push(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {alert(i);}, 0);
            });
        }(i); 
    }
    for(var index in functions) {
        functions[index]();
    }
}();
```